# Traversing all the subarrays of a 2-D array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, dynamic-programming, sub-array

I have a 2-D array given of size P*Q and I have to answer K questions based on the array. The 2-D array given consists of numbers 0 and 1. For each question, we have to count the maximum size of any square subarray in which no two same elements are adjacent.
For example if P=Q=8 and our given array be

```
00101010
00010101
10101010
01010101
10101010
01010101
10101010
01010101
```

Then the question Ki allows us to do Ki number of flips(0's to 1 or 1's to 0.)

```
Here K=4(number of questions)
1 2 0 10001
Output: 7 8 6 8
```

I have understood that as for K1=1, we can change the value of array index(1,1) to 1 and get a 7*7 sized valid matrix, the output is 7. If we have Ki>=2 our answer will be 8. 
What I think is that we have to maintain an array ans[k] which stores the maximum size of a square sub matrix which is valid. For this, we can start each index of the original array and traverse through its sub-arrays and count the value of maximum size for flip=i if we start from this index. We have to do this for the subarrays starting from each index and then store the maximum of them in flip[i].
I have problems implementing this as I don't know how to traverse all the sub-arrays for a given index. I'm trying this for so long but still not achieving it. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Use vector of vectors or array of arrays and two range-based loops. Or implement your own matrix class.

Comment: @Ron Can you explain?

Comment: Just to be clear, the dynamic programming algorithm here is *not* the question, right?

Comment: @Davis that is the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to simplify the problem to depend only on individual values (rather than pairs of neighboring values).  So **XOR** the grid with each **perfect checkerboard**:

```
01111111  10000000
10111111  01000000
11111111  00000000
11111111  00000000
11111111  00000000
11111111  00000000
11111111  00000000
11111111  00000000
```

where the goal is now to find the largest square in *either* grid that has no more than *K_i* 0s (obviously favoring the left one here).

Start with *K_i*=0.  To find the **largest square** of 1s, compute for each cell the number of 1s in a **row** and a **column** starting at it (0 for a cell that contains a 0); the largest **square** with that cell as its upper-left corner (assuming it's a 1) is then one more than the **minimum** of the row length of its right neighbor, the column length of its lower neighbor, and the square-size of its lower-right neighbor.  (All these are 0 for the non-existent cells outside the grid.)  Visit the cells in **diagonal-major** order to have these values available when you need them; note the largest square size produced.

To generalize to *K_i*>0, store for each cell those three values (row length, column length, and square size) for **each number of flips** up to *K_i*.  A cell with a 1 adds 1 to each row/column length as before, while a cell with a 0 **shifts** those lengths to the next flip count, **discarding** those whose flip count is now too large and adding a **new value** of 0 for 0 flips.  For each combination of row-length-east, column-length-south, and square-size-southeast, each with a flip count, a cell gets a **candidate** square size that is their minimum with the *sum* of their flip counts, **plus one** if the cell is a 0 itself.  For each flip count (that isn't too large), keep the largest square size, noting if it is the largest so far encountered (for that flip count).

Note that the brute-force solution may be nearly as fast when the squares are much smaller than the array, since it need visit each one only a small number of times.